# Почему не выгружает 1С данные заказов на сайт?

Tags: php, 1с

Помогите понять причину, при нажатии на обмен сайтом с сайта загружаются данные заказов, при повторной нажатии не выгружаются данные и сам метод 'file' не инициируется, пробовал внутри поставить `fwrite($f, 'Test')`, при запросе с браузера файл создается с текстом при запросе со стороны 1C файл не создается, тоесть факта запроса `file` нет, попробовал поменять заказ количество товара и нажал сохранить далее выполнить обмен всё равно не происходит обмен/инициация GET запроса `file`. В каком случае вообще должен происходит данная инициация? Во всех случаях 1C будет отправлять заказы за весь период или что то если поменять в данном заказе затем?

Comment: Это надо отладкой заниматься. Логи смотреть и т.д. и т.п. Кроме вас это никто не сделает.